# Identifier expected but integer literal found

Tags: scala, function, literals, identifier

I got this problem when writing a recursive function that calculates the number of points where two general functions f1 and f2 are equal(Assuming only Integer values).

```
    object X1 {
    def numEqual(f1:Int=>Int,f2:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int):Int=
    if(a>b) 0 
    else f1(a)==f2(a) ? 1+numEqual(f1,f2)(a+1,b):0+numEqual(f1,f2)(a+1,b)
```

And this is what compiler says :

> X1.scala:5: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
>               f1(a)==f2(a) ? 1+numEqual(f1,f2)(a+1,b) : 0+numEqual(f1,f2)(a+1,b)
>                                                                   ^
>   one error found.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why the downvotes. This question (and the answer) helped me much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` construct in Scala is an expression. As the others already said, there's no ternary operator because there's **no need for it** - the if being already an expression.

I rewrote your function to a tail-recursive version (to avoid `StackOverflowError`s), let's see how it looks:

```scala
@tailrec def numEqual(f1: Int => Int, f2: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int, res: Int = 0): Int =
  if (a > b) res
  else {
    val inc = if (f1(a) == f2(a)) 1 else 0
    numEqual(f1, f2)(a + 1, b, res + inc)
  }
```

Notice how the result of the if expression is assigned to `inc` - here you would normally use the ternary operator. Anyway, I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

the `? :` operator doesn't exist in scala

Answer (score 1):

Scala does not use the ternary operator, http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-ternary-operator-syntax